# Chart.js - generateLegend() call results in "undefined is not a function"

Tags: chart.js

When I attempt to call generateLegened() on my chart:

```
var ctx = $("#chart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var ctxOptions = {
    responsive: false,
    legendTemplate: "<ul>LEGEND</ul>"
};
var chart = new Chart(ctx);

chart.Line(data, ctxOptions);
var legend = chart.generateLegend();
```

it errors with:

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

on the chart.GenerateLegend() line.

I'm completely confused as to what the problem it. The function is clearly in the .js file being included.

I'm using this script: *//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js*

Is this a bug, or can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly, if I change the code as follows:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, ctxOptions);
```

the legend works as expected!?

A bug with chart.js?

Comment: I've logged this as an issue with chart.js.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
legendTemplate: function(data) { return "<ul>LEGEND</ul>"; }
```

instead. Seems like some bug in the chart.js.